# Proving a Base in Topology

Tags: general-topology

how can I show that the collection $\mathscr B = \{(-a,b) \mid a,b \ \text{are positive reals}\}$ is a base for a topology on $\mathbb R$? I know I'm supposed to show that $\mathbb R = \bigcup \{B \mid B \in \mathscr B\}$ and that for any $B_1$ and $B_2$ that are in $\mathscr B$ and any $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there exists a $B_3$ that's in $\mathscr B$ for which $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$, but I have no clue how to get started and applying the theorem to the problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I've added some formatting to your question.  You should click the `edit` button and take a look at what I've done.  You will tend to get better answers faster if you format your question nicely. :)

Comment: @Bill: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). And thanks to Jim for his editing.

Answer (score 4):

If $B_1 = (-a_1,b_1)$ and $B_2 = (-a_2,b_2)$, then what is $B_1 \cap B_2$? Is it in $\mathscr{B}$?

To show that $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of the intervals in $\mathscr{B}$, let $x$ be an arbitrary real number.  Is there some interval $(-a,b)$ that contains $x$?

Comment: wouldn't it be the min of -a1 and -a2 along with the max of b1 and b2?

Comment: @Bill: No, that’s $B_1\cup B_2$, assuming that you mean the interval $(\min\{-a_1,-a_2\},\max\{b_1,b_2\})$; you want the **intersection** $-$ the points that are in **both** $B_1$ **and** $B_2$.

Comment: ok yea I realized that mistake recently...thank you. so then how do I show the first part, that R is the union of all the B's?